# nested html tags in two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to change specified pool in array that is fullfilled with html nested tags for example:

example content:

```
<tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

and this is changed to dynamically:

```
    let array=[];
    for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
        let children=[];
        for(let j=0;j<3;j++){
            children.push(<td key={`${i}${j}`}>{j}</td>);
        }   
    array.push(<tr key={`${i}`}>{children}</tr>);       
    }
   ///////////////////////////////////////
```

I've tried to iterate in the way but an error occures:

```
 for(let i in array){
     for(let j in array[i])
     array[i][j]=<td>{some other content}</td>;
 }
```

I need to make it possible to change specified pool, for example:

```
array[row][column]=<td key={`${i}${j}`}>{k}</td>   // it doesnt work
```

Comment: "An error occures". Can you please be a little more specific :p

Comment: Do you have any particular reason for not simply using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) twice?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '$$typeof' of object '#<Object>'

Comment: Yes it would be better to do it without map becaus every pool need to be very responsible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs because you're trying to update/mutate an multidimensional `array` in a react environment which for some good reason has `strict` mode enabled.

You need to make a deep copy of the multidimensional `array` to overcome this issue. You may use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Assuming `array` is a state variable:

```
this.state = {      
      array: []
};
```

Add a function to set the initial `array` values:

```
initArray = () => {
    let array = [];
    for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
      let children=[];
      for(let j=0;j<3;j++){
          children.push(<td key={`${i}${j}`}>{j}</td>);
      }   
      array.push(<tr key={`${i}`}>{children}</tr>);       
    }
    this.setState({array}, () => console.log("DONE: ", this.state.array));
  }
```

Run the `initArray` method when the component mounts:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.initArray ();
  }
```

Render the contents, and add a button to update `array` contents which is basically what you need.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>

          {this.state.array}

          <button id="btn" onClick={this.updateArray}>UPDATE</button>

        </div>
    );
  }
```

Now the updateArray method:

```
updateArray = () => { 

    let array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.array.length; i++)
        array[i] = this.state.array[i].props.children.slice(); 


    console.log("ADONE: ", array)
     for(let i in array){
      for(let j in array[i]){        
        array[i][j]=<td>{i*j}</td>;
      }       
    }
    this.setState({array}, () => console.log("DONE: ", this.state.array));
  }
```

Check out the [Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-u7pybc?file=index.js)